# How to convert 21h to 13h or 10h interrupt usage in emu 8086 hello world code

Tags: assembly, emulation, interrupt, x86-16

```
; emu8086 version 4.00-Beta-12 or better is required! 
; put file named "input.txt" to c:\emu8086\vdrive\c\ 
; (it's possible to copy "ReadMe.txt" and rename it or use any other 


org 100h ; .com memory layout 

mov dx, offset db; address of file to dx 
mov al,0 ; open file (read-only) 
mov ah,3dh 
int 21h ; call the interupt 
jc terminate ; if error occurs, terminate program 
mov bx,ax ; put handler to file in bx 

mov cx,1 ; read one character at a time 
print: 
lea dx, BUF 
mov ah,3fh ; read from the opened file (its handler in bx) 
int 21h 
CMP AX, 0 ; how many bytes transfered? 
JZ terminate ; end program if end of file is reached (no bytes 

mov al, BUF ; char is in BUF, send to ax for printing (char is 

mov ah,0eh ; print character (teletype). 
int 10h 
jmp print ; repeat if not end of file. 


terminate: 
mov ah, 0 ; wait for any key... 
int 16h 
ret 

db " Hello World! ", 0 
BUF db ? 


END
```

Comment: so what do you want to ask?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for those interrupts to see how they work, and have you made an attempt yourself? Exactly where are you stuck? Are you having trouble understanding the documentation for `int 13h` or `int 10h`? You can Google `BIOS "int 13h"` and `BIOS "int 10h"` for more information. There's no BIOS interrupt to open a file since the BIOS doesn't know what file system you are using. The `int 21h` assumes a DOS FAT file system, so it can open the file. If you want to use `int 13h` for that, you have a lot of work to do since that's cylinder/sector/block level.

Comment: Here's link for [DOS and BIOS interrupts](http://www.oneonta.edu/faculty/higgindm/assembly/DOS_AND_ROM_BIOS_INTS.htm). Note the difference between `INT 13h / AH = 02h` (which reads sectors from a disk) and `INT 21h / AH= 3Dh` which opens a file assuming a FAT (DOS) file system. You would have to interpret the file system yourself using `INT 13h`. What's the purpose of this exercise?